# ListView ContextMenu Active State Color

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I'm trying to get my ListView to have three background color states.

1. normal
2. pressed (when the user's finger is touching)
3. context menu active (when the context menu appears for a specific item)

*note: I don't have a need for a selected state when the context menu is NOT active.*

Basically, the part I'm having a hard time with is #3. When a user long-presses a listview item, I want the context menu to show, but I also want the item they pressed to highlight a different color.

In code, I have this

```
// note: the names are just to tell you what view type we're dealing with.
// android_Widgit_ListView: the ListView
// android_Views_View: the Cell
if (android_Widgit_ListView != null)
{
    android_Views_View.Background = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(context, Resource.Drawable.listview_selector);
    android_Widgit_ListView.SetSelector(Resource.Drawable.listview_selector);
    android_Widgit_ListView.CacheColorHint = Color.Transparent.ToAndroid();
}
```

And I have a selector (note the different colors just to see what's up)

```
<!-- listview_selector.xml -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/PrimaryMediumBlue"/>
  <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/PrimaryYellow"/>
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/SecondaryWarmGrey"/>
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/SecondaryGreen"/>
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/SecondaryLightGrey"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

The problem is that when I long-press the item to bring up the context menu, the list view item returns to white.

How do I get that state to stay a different color?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit of a workaround but...

You could bind a color changing function to a property in the context menu.

ex: a bool called "active" that you set "OnAppering" and "OnDisapering".

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire an event when the active property is changed.

and then listen for the event in the listview and change the color on that.

-

i am not sure this is the best way...

Comment: I went down that path. Xamarin.Forms has internal/sealed all of the ContextMenu bits :(

Comment: Damm sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewHighlighted</item>
</style>
<color name="ListViewHighlighted">#A8A8A8</color>
```

add this on `Resourses>Values>Styles.xml`